# Babel option clash for multilingual document

Tags: french, spanish, option-clash

I'm writing a report in french, which also contains references to spanish names, containing spanish accents. Including both the french and spanish babel options creates a babel package clash error.

How do I use both languages in my document in a simple way?

Thanks

Comment: use `\usepackage[spanish,french]{babel}` not `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}\usepackage[french]{babel}`

Comment: Note that you only need spanish option to enable Spanish hyphenation patterns and to use Spanish words for fixed texts such as "Table of Contents" the letters are available anyway (`\~{n}` etc).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could be interested by `csquotes` and `biblatex` packages in order to handle accents for different language in the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{spanish}{babel}
\documentclass{...}
...
```

if you cannot do what David suggested.